# Как мне сделать раскрывающий строки таблицы?

Tags: reactjs

Мне нужно сделать примерно такой эффект https://jsfiddle.net/rusline/x2bcukw7/4/ Конечно нужно еще и чтобы когда ты другую строку нажимаешь, то все открытые строки сворачивается.
Только когда я начал делать на react то у меня возник ступор как все это реализовать
https://codepen.io/rusline/pen/xpEzPy?editors=0010

```js
class Product extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <tr onClick={<RowColumn />}>
            <td key={this.props.product.id}>{this.props.product.id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.product.name}</td>
          </tr>
    )
  }
}

class RowColumn extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>Hello</div>
    )
  }
}

class GridView extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.product.map(n => <Product product={n}/>
         )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

const СATEGORY = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Канцтовары',
    createAt: '2017-12-12 10:00:00' 
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Мебель',
    createAt: '2017-12-12 11:00:00' 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Электроника',
    createAt: '2017-12-15 08:30:00' 
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Бытовая техника',
    createAt: '2017-12-12 10:00:00' 
  },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <GridView product = {СATEGORY}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример битый, так как нельзя внедрить <div> между <tr>, <td> и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/6xw884n6pr

```
class GridView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeRow: null
    }
  }

  getRows() {
    const rows = [];

    this.props.data.forEach(product => {

      const isOpen = product.id === this.state.activeRow;

      rows.push(<ProductStyled
        key={product.id}
        product={product}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onOpen={() => this.setState({ activeRow: product.id })}
      />);

      if (isOpen) {
        rows.push(<Sub key="sub" />);
      }

    });

    return rows;
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.getRows()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}




const Product = ({ className, product, isOpen, onOpen }) => {
  return (
      <tr className={className} onClick={onOpen}>
        <td key={product.id}>{product.id}</td>
        <td>{product.name}</td>
      </tr>  
  );
}

const ProductStyled = styled(Product)`
  background-color: ${p => p.isOpen ? 'LightSteelBlue ' : 'inherit' };
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;



const Sub = () => (
  <div>This is me</div>
);
```

Comment: У меня вопрос такой, а зачем нужен данный код this.state = {
      activeRow: null
    } И такой еще вопрос, если нажать еще раз на строку, то как я в реакте могу создать закрытие. Просто мне тот код не совсем понятен зачем он нужен, но без него некорректно работает

Comment: Просто я пытаюсь добавить onOpen={() => {
            true ? this.setState({ activeRow: product.id }) : null
          }
        } Но пока react я не сосем освоил

Comment: Привет Руслан! 1) `this.state = { activeRow: null }` нужно чтобы задать начальное состояние. В прицнипе, в данном случае, это можно не делать, т.к. js очень нестрогий язык, но это хорошая практика, т.к. сразу видна структура нашего состояния. Так что рекомендую описывать подобные вещи заранее.  2) Чтобы описать закрытие, Вы в общем-то на правильном пути, но написать надо так: `onOpen={() => { this.setState({ activeRow: this.state.activeRow ? null : product.id }) }` } `

Comment: И в таком случае лучше переименовать событие onOpen. Я обновил пример, можете посмотреть.. https://codesandbox.io/s/6xw884n6pr

Comment: Спасибо большое